# iOS memory management when accessing singleton method (ARC)

Tags: ios, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

Suppose we have Singleton class named SingletonClass. We can access it by

```
[SingletonClass SharedInstance]
```

Now when we access its method by doing below in any other class say ClassOther

```
__weak singletonObj = [SingletonClass SharedInstance];
[singletonObj methodA];
```

So singletonObj weak linked and released properly when ClassOther's object released.

But if I try

```
[SingletonClass SharedInstance] methodA];
```

When ClassOther gets released does it release everything corrosponds to SingletonClass? i.e. Does it go in loop and does not released ClassOther as we access SingletonClass and its not weak linked?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the SharedInstance method of SingletonClass is in fact a correct implementation of the singleton pattern, once the SingletonClass is initialized the first time through SharedInstance, it should be alive through the rest of the time that the app is alive.

The whole point of the Singleton pattern is to have an single instance of that object which is shared.

There is no point for you to do something like this

```
__weak singletonObj = [SingletonClass SharedInstance];
[singletonObj methodA];
```

since the same object can always be accessed when you call SharedInstance.  It does not matter what ClassOther does and should not, an instance of SingletonClass should stay in memory from the point that the first time SharedInstance is called to when the application is cleared from memory.

Answer (score 1):

SharedInstance should be lowercase, sharedInstance.

If you create the singleton object with the generally accepted pattern (using a static variable and dispatch_once) it will be created once and stay in memory forever. How to do this has been answered dozens of times, so just search for it.

There is absolutely no reason to be faffing around with weak or strong or whatever pointers when using a singleton object.